# PKCS#11: Which CKK_types are supported by CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2?

Tags: pbkdf-2, pkcs11

On Solaris there's a function `pkcs11_PasswdToKey`() which is a wrapper of `C_GenerateKey`(). I made a simple test and it turned out that `pkcs11_PasswdToKey`() only supports following `CKK_`types:

```
CKK_AES
CKK_BLOWFISH
CKK_DES
CKK_DES2
CKK_DES3
CKK_RC4
```

From my understanding, other symmetric ciphers (like `CKK_IDEA`) should also be supported. Can anyone make some clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with that specific Solaris library (is that a software token?).

However, what I can say is that PKCS#11 does not set any minimum requirement for the algorithms that a certain implementation should offer. `CKK_IDEA` *could* be supported, but only if the implementer chooses to. For instance, up to a few years ago, IDEA was patented and it was often not included in libraries and devices for legal reasons.

Besides, that is there any good reason not to use `CKK_AES`? That is the best choice in most cases.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you're right that it's implementation dependent.